# How to perform DE analysis for each sample

Tags: differential-expression, microarray, limma

I am new to R and biocondunctor. I have the normalized expression values for 20 samples for a disease and for 10 controls. I wanted to get the differential expressed values for each sample with all 10 controls.

How could I do that with limma.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: What I want to achieve is single-sample t-test between the control population and the single sample values to get DE values

Comment: You need raw count data, and let limma normalize it (with e.g., voom). Read the manual, it is pretty well written.

Comment: @benn But I have the normalized data already, I want to get single expression values

Comment: Try to get raw counts.

Comment: @benn Ok , and then, I should normalize with voom, after which how should I get DE values for each sample separately?

Comment: Please go over the limma manual (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf)  and edit your question with the potential problems you will encounter. Be careful to use the right section given the technology used (microarray or RNA-seq).

Comment: @haci Hey, I have added the microarray tag, I am sorry for the confusion

Comment: Okay I assumed it was RNAseq... Just read the manual...

Comment: @benn I am sorry if I have confused you, I tried to find this in the manual but I could not find any instance of comparing single sample vs a population

Comment: If you do statistics you compare groups, not separate samples. Separate samples do not have information about variance which is needed for statistics.

Comment: @benn But what I am doing is One Sample t Test. It may not have meaning as such, but I wanted to try it out with DE Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat your disease samples as individual groups and then follow the normal routine in limma to use contrasts to compare two group (the control group versus individual disease samples). Note that you need to think long and hard about what these results then mean. Normally we compare groups because then the results should generalize to other samples. That will not be the case when you look at individual disease samples, so I suggest you do some clustering of the samples to see if you perhaps have any coherent clustering of the disease samples into subsets that could then be used as more useful groups in DE testing.

Comment: Thanks for the help!